# java classpath mystery: either my classes or a jar, but not both?

Tags: java, classpath, jna

Consider the following java program:

```
import computer_package.Computer;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

and the following directory structure:

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ find computer_package/
computer_package/
computer_package//Computer.class
computer_package//Computer.java
```

wherein `Computer.java` is as follows:

```
package computer_package;
public class Computer {
    public Computer() {
        System.out.println("Constructor of Computer class.");
    }
    public void computer_method() {
        System.out.println("Power gone! Shut down your PC soon...");
    }
}
```

and another directory with just `jar` files:

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ find com
com
com/sun
com/sun/jna
com/sun/jna/jna-4.0.0.jar
com/sun/jna/jna-platform-4.0.0.jar
```

If I comment out just the `import com.sun.jna;` line in the original `HelloWorld.java` file, then all works well

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ javac -g HelloWorld.java 
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ java HelloWorld
Constructor of Computer class.
Hello, World
```

Javac and java are able to find the class file `./computer_package/Computer.class` without any further hints or annotation or classpath-hacking.

Now, if I restore the `import com.sun.jna;` line and comment out just the `import computer_package.Computer;` line and the line the constructs a `new Computer`, and compile like this:

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ javac -g -cp "./com/sun/jna/jna-4.0.0.jar" HelloWorld.java
```

or even like this:

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ make
javac -g -cp "./com/sun/jna/jna-4.0.0.jar:./computer_package" HelloWorld.java
```

then all is still well:

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ java HelloWorld
Hello, World
```

At least, the `import com.sun.jna;` line didn't throw a compiler error -- admittedly, I am not *yet* using the jna library; I'm just trying to build up to that momentous achievement in baby steps.

So if I now cautiously uncomment the `import computer_package;` line and the line that constructs an instance of `Computer`, yielding the `HelloWorld.java` file at the top of this question that tries to use *both* my `Computer` class *and* jna, all hell breaks loose; the previously acceptable `Computer` class is now inaccessible:

```
Rebs-MacBook-Pro:jalint2 rebcabin$ make
javac -g -cp "./com/sun/jna/jna-4.0.0.jar:./computer_package" HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:20: error: package computer_package does not exist
import computer_package.Computer;
                       ^
HelloWorld.java:25: error: cannot access Computer
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        ^
  bad class file: ./computer_package/Computer.class
    class file contains wrong class: computer_package.Computer
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
2 errors
make: *** [HelloWorld.class] Error 1
```

I know this is elementary; I am not a java expert and I admit I am trying to guess my way around the classpath nightmare world; I am using just emacs and bash, avoiding the IDEs that add even more layers of opaque abstraction.

Comment: I eliminated the distraction of the jna file and posted a simpler case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177908/implicit-classpath-works-but-explicit-classpaths-dont; looks like @SimonC's answer here is the correct one for that case, too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, no worries!

Comment: I deleted the other, simpler case since this one was answered first (my post of the other question was in-flight when this answer came in:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath as the directory containing the *package*, not the package's classes, so if you're running from the same directory:

```
javac -g -cp "./com/sun/jna/jna-4.0.0.jar:./"
```

Note that, when you don't specify a classpath, the current directory is used by default.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html